# How to test a method which is internally getting values from other class methods

Tags: android, mockito, retrofit, android-testing

I tried several ways to mock and spy the values and call below method every time I am ending up with nullPointerException or other Mockito errors.
As I new to Mockito and android itself please let know how to write the AndroidTest case for below method which also uses Retrofit API calls.
I am trying to code cover the entire method.
Thanks in advance

```
    public  LiveData<BaseModel<Onboarding>> updateUser(Result item) {
            final MutableLiveData<BaseModel<Onboarding>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
            final BaseModel<Onboarding> dataWrapper = new BaseModel<>();
            Map<String, String> headers = WaApplication.getContext().getRequestHeaders();
            String tenantId = WaApplication.getContext().getTenantId();
            
            service.updateUser(tenantId,headers, item).enqueue(new Callback<UserOnboarding>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Onboarding> call, Response<Onboarding> response) {
                    dataWrapper.setData(response.body());
                    dataWrapper.setResponseCode(response.code());
                    data.setValue(dataWrapper);
                    LogUtils.d(TAG, "updateUser:HTTPS_ONBOARDING_API_ENDPOINT: "+ BuildConfig.HTTPS_ONBOARDING_API_ENDPOINT);
                    LogUtils.d("OnBoardingService onRes", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Onboarding> call, Throwable t) {
                    LogUtils.e(TAG, "OnBoardingService API Failed. Error - " + t.getMessage());
                    data.setValue(null);
                }
            });
            return data;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

```
@Rule 
public InstantTaskExecutorRule InstantTaskExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();
```

*I'm assuming you want to write an unit test (runs on JVM) and not an Instrumentation test (runs on Android device).*

In an unit test your call to [data.setValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#setValue(T)) will lead to:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
```

To be able to use Android classes in a unit test on a JVM the `android.jar` is added to the classpath. This jar contains all Android classes but without their implementation. So if you execute any of its code it instead always throws the above exception. The real implementation of the Android method calls is only available on Android devices.

So in general for unit tests you would have to mock the method calls with e.g. Mockito.

Alternatively you could execute your test as Instrumentation test (put it inside `androidTest` source set). Then they are executed on Android devices.

In the case of `LiveData` though, you can circumvent that by changing the way `LiveData` is dispatched. Google provides a JUnit [TestRule](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html) for that case, you have to add one artifact to your `build.gradle` and the `TestRule` to your test class

build.gradle:

```
testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
```

Test class:

```
@Rule 
public InstantTaskExecutorRule InstantTaskExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();
```

**On a sidenote:**

- Don't do network or `Retrofit` calls to real URLs inside your unit test. Better point the `baseUrl` to a mock server and fake your network responses with e.g. [OkHttp MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver)
- If you don't have the `updateUser` method in your `ViewModel` you want to put it there. Because that is exactly the use case for a `ViewModel`.
- If you have the `updateUser` method in a `ViewModel`, then you don't need to return the `LiveData`. The `data` `LiveData` should be an instance variable of your `ViewModel` which you then can observe in your `Activity` or `Fragment`.
- You might want to use the android de-facto log standard [Timber](https://github.com/jakewharton/timber) instead of a custom `LogUtils`.